# GridFilter is Not Working With NULL value

Tags: filter, sonata-admin

I have a database entry like below and try to search record using advance filter with NULL value, but does not contain filter is not working.

[image]

Result looks like below:

[image]

Code is for grid filter.

```
$dataGridMapper->add('translations.name','',array('label' => 'Name'));
```

Entity Main:

```
/**
     * @var LeadingServiceTranslations[]
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="LeadingServiceTranslations", mappedBy="leadingServices", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $translations;
```

Entity Translations :

```
 /**
         * @ORM\manyToOne(targetEntity="LeadingServices", inversedBy="translations")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="leading_services_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
         */
        private $leadingServices;
```

I also tried callback function for filter like below but it gives me error :

```
$dataGridMapper->add('name', 'doctrine_orm_callback', array(
                'callback' => function($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value) {
                    if (!$value['value']) {
                        return;
                    }
                    $queryBuilder->leftJoin(sprintf('%s.LeadingServiceTranslations', $alias), 'lst');
                    $queryBuilder->andWhere('lst.name IS NOT NULL');
                    return true;
                },
            ))
        ;
```

Can anyone tell me what is missing in this code ?

Thank You